# Selenium can not able to get text of the temporary email from the element within https://www.temporary-mail.net/

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm trying to get text of an element in the temp mail website which is;

https://www.temporary-mail.net/

My purpose is to get temp mail as a string

the CSS : "input#active-mail"
XPATH = "//*[@id="active-mail"]"

i tried to use **.text** and **get_attribute()** methods, but failed!

I could not get the text of the CSS element, am i doing something wrong? As far as I can see it is not in the iFrame but I'm not sure, can someone enlighten me ?

codes:

```
    driver.get("https://www.temporary-mail.net/")
    kontrol = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="active-mail"]'))
    )
    time.sleep(1)
    tmpMail_text = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="active-mail"]').text
    #or
    tmpMail_attr = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="active-mail"]').get_attribute("data-clipboard-text")
    print(tmpMail_text )
    print(tmpMail_attr )
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To print the value of the *temporary -mail* e.g. `68p7wixe@temporary-mail.net` you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.temporary-mail.net/')
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#active-mail"))).get_attribute("data-clipboard-text"))
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.temporary-mail.net/')
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='active-mail']"))).get_attribute("data-clipboard-text"))
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  68p7wixe@temporary-mail.net
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Update

As an alternative instead of `visibility_of_element_located()` you can also try `element_to_be_clickable()` as follows:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='active-mail']"))).get_attribute("data-clipboard-text"))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='active-mail']"))).get_attribute("data-clipboard-text"))
  ```

Comment: firstly thx for your answer, i updated my question as real code snippet. I already tried your solution but, it didnt work. Did you try and achieve with these methods coz I dont :(

Comment: @FatihTüz Generally, I don't publish answers with untested lines of code.

Comment: I didnt want to be rude, sorry i you understand me in a wrong way. I again tried just your code with neccesary imports. 

C:\Users\MFT\PycharmProjects\investing\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/MFT/PycharmProjects/investing/deneme.py


Process finished with exit code 0

this is the output. I'm using chromedriver 85. Could there be any other problem?

Comment: @FatihTüz Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: It solved, great! I have one more question, why did you change your idea as an element to be clickable? If i have this or any other situation again, how can I decide to make these changes? I mean is there any clue for element_to_be_clickable

Comment: @FatihTüz Honestly I admire your question because very less programmers try to get whats happening under the hood. The logic is `visibility_of_element_located` refers to `width` and `height` greater then `0` but `element to be clickable` refers to the interactive state. As the element is an `<input>` element incase `visibility_of_element_located` failed we can always fall back on `element to be clickable` clause. Checkout the [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603847/how-to-sleep-webdriver-in-python-for-milliseconds/52607451#52607451) link.

Comment: Thanks for all your help! and your thought. Now I got the idea :)